# Determine the winner on a 3x3 TicTacToe game

Tags: c#, matrix

I have to find the winner of a 3x3 TicTacToe game player vs player. Firsty, I have to user input N (number of moves) and then N moves like (1 2) (0 1) etc. each on new line, X has the first move, 0 second move and so on.  First number from bracket is representing the row index and second number representing column index. The program needs to return the winner X or 0, or draw if there is not a winner.
For example for the following input:

- 7
- 1 1
- 2 1
- 2 0
- 0 2
- 1 0
- 1 2
- 0 0
  The output is : X

I've tried this code, but nothing is shown in console. Any hint would be really apreciated.

```
using System;
​
namespace ConsoleApp20
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string Tictactoe(int[,] moves)
        {
            int[] rowsValues = new int[3];
            int[] columnsValues = new int[3];
            int diagonalSum = 0;
            int antiDiagonalSum = 0;
            const int c1 = 3;
            bool isFirstPlayer = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < c1; i++)
            {
                int rowIndex = moves[i, 0];
                int columnIndex = moves[i, 1];
                int value = isFirstPlayer ? 1 : -1;
​
                if (rowIndex == columnIndex)
                {
                    diagonalSum += value;
                }
​
                if (columnIndex == c1 - rowIndex - 1)
                {
                    antiDiagonalSum += value;
                }
​
                rowsValues[rowIndex] += value;
                columnsValues[columnIndex] += value;
                if (Math.Abs(diagonalSum) == c1 ||
                   Math.Abs(antiDiagonalSum) == c1 ||
                   Math.Abs(rowsValues[rowIndex]) == c1 ||
                   Math.Abs(columnsValues[columnIndex]) == c1)
                {
                    return isFirstPlayer ? "X" : "0";
                }
​
                isFirstPlayer = !isFirstPlayer;
            }
​
            return "Draw";
        }
​
        public static void Main()
        {
           Tictactoe(ReadValues());
        }
​
        public static int[,] ReadValues()
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[,] movesArr = new int[n, 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                string[] moves = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                int a = int.Parse(moves[0]);
                int b = int.Parse(moves[1]);
                movesArr[i, 0] = a;
                movesArr[i, 1] = b;
            }
​
            return movesArr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you writing the output from your console app?

Comment: what you need to do is debug your code.... we also have to do the same thing... then why don't you do it and figure what's the wrong with the code. If you find the problem which you cant' fix, you can share the details of the problem here.

Comment: You are so close. You just missed to write the result of the TicTacToe function to the console.

Comment: Console.Writeline inside the function?

Comment: No, in the Main, write the result of your Tictactoe call - you return a result and now ignore it

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Tictactoe(ReadValues()));`

Comment: Thank you. For the test case from problem's statement it returns me "Draw" instead of "x"

Comment: As a debug step, try and use those `moves` to fill out a grid with O's and X's and print it: is that OK? Then maybe use that "OX grid" to check for a winner

Comment: It's problem solved.